# client or server is removing umlauts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, base64, php-5.2

I am using `btoa` to encode my string to base64. However, it does not seem to work correctly, any umlauts are removed for whatever reason.

I tried to demonstrate it, but on this page it works:

```js
var content = "This text contains umlauts (ÖÜÄ) they will be removed on my webpage, but not in this demo for whatever reason";

alert(content);

content = btoa(content);

alert(content);

content = atob(content);

alert(content);
```

But it does not work on my webpage:

[image]

This is the value of the parameter `content`:

```
PHA+VGhpcyB0ZXh0IGNvbnRhaW5zIHVtbGF1dHMgKMTc1ikuIExldHMgc2VlIGlmIHRoZXkgYXJlIGdldHRpbmcgcmVtb3ZlZC48L3A+
```

If you decode this base64 encoded string [here](https://www.base64decode.org/) then you will get this result:

> This text contains umlauts (). Lets see if they are getting
>   removed.

As you can see the umlauts where removed for whatever reason.

This is a snippet from the code where I encode the string, it is used to post a news entry to a blog:

---

**EDIT**: The code below suddenly works without any change. See other edit below for more infos.

---

```
var content = $(".ql-editor").html();

$.ajax({
    url: "ajax.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
        action: "postNews",
        autor: autor,
        content: btoa(content),
        date: date
    },
    success: function(response) {

        if (response.indexOf("error") === -1) {
            $("#statusBoxMessage").html("Ihr Eintrag wurde erfolgreich veröffentlicht.");
            $("#statusBoxImage").attr("src", "gfx/page/checkmark.jpg");
            showStatusBox("success");
        } else {

            $("#statusBoxMessage").html("Fehler! Der Eintrag konnte nicht erstellt werden! (" + response + ")");
            $("#statusBoxImage").attr("src", "gfx/page/fail.jpg");
            showStatusBox("fail");  
        }
    },
    error: function(response) {
        $("#statusBoxMessage").html("Fehler! " + response);
        showStatusBox("fail");
    }
});
```

---

EDIT: I also have an almost identical script which I use to edit a news entry from the blog, it does still not work and drops any umlauts:

---

```
$("#submitEditContent").click(function() {

    var content = $("#editEditor").val();
    var s = 0;

    if (target == "pages/news.html" || target == "news.html") {
        target = currentNewsFilename;
        s = 1;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            action: "postEdit",
            content: btoa(content),
            target: target
        },
        success: function(response) {
            if (response == "success") {
                if (s == 0) {
                    window.location.replace("index.php?page=" + target);
                } else {
                    window.location.reload();
                }

            } else {
                console.warn(response);
            }
        }
    });
```

I hope someone can explain why the first script suddenly stopped dropping the umlauts and why the second script still drops umlauts.

I tested it with the latest chrome browser.

Comment: Now I can explain it, the site https://www.base64decode.org/ is the culprit... it does not decode correctly and drops all my umlauts, I always used that site to test it, the site really confused me. I only noticed it after using atop for decoding to test if it makes a differnce. The reason why the one script seemed to work, is because both are running different server code.

Comment: The site _is_ capable of doing the decoding, as I mention in my answer below.  You just have to use the right encoding setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let decoded = atob('PHA+VGhpcyB0ZXh0IGNvbnRhaW5zIHVtbGF1dHMgKMTc1ikuIExldHMgc2VlIGlmIHRoZXkgYXJlIGdldHRpbmcgcmVtb3ZlZC48L3A+')
console.log(decoded)
```

I don't think there's anything wrong with the encoding on your webpage.

This works perfectly fine in the browser.  *And* it works on the external site you referenced, but you need to set the encoding to ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8.  Give it a try.[image]

Comment: Why is it not working with UTF-8 then? I always use `<meta charset='UTF-8'>` on every website to enable umlauts. I am confused, it should work with UTF-8.

Comment: The string is ISO-8859-1 encoded.  It's not UTF-8 encoded.  You can verify this EG by using Python to decode it: `base64.b64decode(encoded).decode('ISO-8859-1')` gives `<p>This text contains umlauts (ÄÜÖ). Lets see if they are getting removed.</p>`, but if you specify `UTF-8` decoding, you get a parsing error.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it thanks to @Matt Morgans's hints. We found out that everything was working fine client side, I had to change server side code.

**Before:**

```
$content = $_POST["content"];
$content = stripScript(base64_decode($content));
$content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8', 'OLD-ENCODING');
```

**After:**

```
$content = $_POST["content"];
$content = stripScript(base64_decode($content));
$content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8', 'Windows-1252');
```

This works too:

```
$content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1');
```